# Regex to split id's

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression so a string can be split on the above ID's.

```
T followed by 9 digits (eg. T123654789)
or
S followed by 9 digits (eg. S123654789)
or 
E followed by 9 digits (eg. E123654789)
```

I have this but does not seem to work.

```
"^[S][0-9]{9}?$|^[T][0-9]{9}?$|^[E][0-9]{9}?$"
```

This works on regxr.com but not in my program

```
"/([S]|[E]|[T])[1-9]{9}/g"
```

Comment: Sounds like a homework assignment.

Comment: Is there anything you've tried so far?

Comment: This seems like a pretty basic regex.  Show us what you've tried and we'll help you get it the rest of the way.

Comment: SO is a resource for solving programming problems, not for teaching you a particular paradigm. If you need to learn about regular expressions, I recommend the excellent http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: This question shows absolutely minimal effort. Remember, [so] is not your personal code-writing service.

Comment: I have this but does not seem to work. "^[S][0-9]{9}?$|^[T][0-9]{9}?$|^[E][0-9]{9}?$"

Comment: This works on regxr.com but not in my programme "/([S]|[E]|[T])[1-9]{9}/g"

Comment: When you have extra information, please [edit] your question - that makes it easier to find that info. And then also show the input string.

Comment: I have edited your question with your regexes.  In the future your code should go into the question.

Comment: I'm not sure this question should be closed since it is clear and shows effort

Comment: @Sayse It shows an effort toward testing particular expressions, but the attempted expressions show a clear lack of understanding of regex at a fundamental level, and thus a lack of effort toward learning before attempting to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `[TSE]{1}[0-9]{9}`
Hope it helps.

Comment: You could leave out the `{1}`, it's implicit.

Comment: Or `[STE]\d{9}`